Is it possible to set different certificates for signing and encryption in Keycloak using SAML metadata?
I'm trying to configure an Identity Provider (IdP) in Keycloak using SAML metadata that contains different certificates for signing and encryption. The metadata looks like this:
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="entername">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>

In this metadata, one certificate is specified for signing and another for encryption. However, when configuring Keycloak, it seems like I can only set one certificate for both signing and encryption.
Is it possible in Keycloak to assign different certificates for signing and encryption using SAML metadata, or is this a limitation of the current Keycloak implementation? If it's possible, how can I achieve this configuration?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!
